# What is wrong with the way I have initialized 'temps'?

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayMethod {

    static int[] temps;

    public static void create() {
         temps = {28, 27, 28, 21, 21, 19, 18, 29, 31, 24};

    }
}
```

I am required to use 'temps' in other methods but am getting a variety of errors.

Comment: "a variety of errors" for example?

Comment: `temps = new int[]{28, 27, 28, 21, 21, 19, 18, 29, 31, 24};`

Comment: Why not just assign the value?   static int[] temps = new int[] {28, 27, 28, 21, 21, 19, 18, 29, 31, 24};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize your array as below. The way you are using would give compile time error because array constants can only be used in initializers

```
temps = new int[]{28, 27, 28, 21, 21, 19, 18, 29, 31, 24};
```

Answer (score 0):

to initialize array, use

```
temps = new int[] {...};
```